# A column definition list is required message when using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, wildfly

Am using the @NamedStoredProcedureQuery annotation to call a stored  procedure from hibernate. My stored procedure returns fields from 2 tables and I can call it from postgresql as below:

```
select * from sp_select_employees t (id int, emp_name text, emp_department text)
```

I want to call that stored procedure from hibernate, but I get "A column definition list is required". I know its because hibernate is not including the

```
 t (id int, emp_name text, emp_department text)
```

part. How do I do this in hibernate? Below is my JPA class

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
 name = "SelectEmployees",
 resultClasses = EmployeeDetails.class,
 procedureName = "sp_select_employees"

)

public class Employees implements java.io.Serializable {
....
}
```

My code where I call hibernate

```
public List<EmployeeDetailsDTO> getEmployeeDetails()
{

  StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("SelectEmployees");
  final List<EmployeeDetails> searchResults = query.getResultList();

  final List<EmployeeDetailsDTO> results = new ArrayList<EmployeeDetailsDTO>();
  for (Campaigns searchResult : searchResults)
  {
     EmployeeDetailsDTO dto = new EmployeeDetailsDTO(searchResult);
     results.add(dto);
  }
  return results;     

}
```

Comment: Change your procedure so it `RETURNS TABLE` or add `OUT` parameters, so you don't rely on sending a column definition list. Or use a native query in Hibernate.

Comment: Yes hibernate NamedStoredProcedureQuery does not support column definition list. Thanks, your suggestion works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your procedure so it `RETURNS TABLE` or add `OUT` parameters, so you don't rely on sending a column definition list. Or use a native query in Hibernate.

A column definition list, and queries that return `record`, are PostgreSQL extensions that Hibernate does not support directly.